# Issues using Sublime Text 3.2.2 (Win10)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just stared to learn HTML5 code and i am using sublime text as code editor. So, i am coding an assigment where i need to use `:hover` a pseudo class selector, but it is not working on my sublime text.
I leave you a photo of what it looks like.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11PFX.png)

Comment: Just so you know, Sublime Text is just a text editor – it sounds like you're having a more general CSS issue, not to do with Sublime Text since you're able to type in the characters you want.

Comment: I get it. But when I type in and assing it to a element of HTML It does not work. It does not modify.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Comment: This has nothing to do with Sublime Text. I have deleted the tag, please [edit] your question and rewrite it to focus on the actual problem, using the guidance I gave above.